# How is accuracy get affected (gain, loss) when applying Monotonic constrain in XGBoost?

Tags: machine-learning, boosting

Can anyone suggest forcing monotonicity in noisy data decreases the accuracy of XGBOOST?

Comment: Hi, welcome. Please include relevant hyperlink(s), e.g. to monotonicity constraints (this perhaps: http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/monotonic.html). Further, expand on what your exact issue is. Thank you – *Reviewer*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XGBoost constructs a model by optimization. Monotonicity enforces a constraint on that model, and creates a *constrained optimization* problem. It's always true that constrained optimization problems have optima which are are *at best* as good as the unconstrained problem; if the constraint is active, then the optima must be worse than in the unconstrained problem.

Stated another way, monotonic models enforce that increasing (decreasing) the value of a feature can only increase (decrease) the value of the response. Sometimes we want to do this because we know it's physically impossible for some process to increase-then-decrease-then-increase, or we have other relevant knowledge. But if oscillation truly a part of process we're modeling, then monotonicity constraints will obviously make the model worse.